# Why background image is overflow the footer?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

https://ibb.co/m9QvTND

Live
http://nafidev.com/t1/

Background image is overflow footer.

```
body {
    background-image: url(../img/planet.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Footer:

```
.footer {
    padding-top: 5rem;
    padding-bottom: 5rem;
    background-color: #2c3e50;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Footer will stay in the last. I don't want to fixed the footer, then content will go under footer.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website OR off-site example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: @Paulie_D, Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why the body bg is overflowing, but if you want the planet background to stop with the footer, you can wrap the HTML inside of another element and apply the background setting to that element.

```
<body>
    <div class="main-wrapper">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">...</nav>
        <!-- Image Section -->
        <section class="page-section portfolio" id="portfolio">...</section>
        <!-- Copyright Section -->
        <section class="copyright py-4 text-center text-white">...</section>
    </div> <!-- close main-wrapper -->
</body>
```

Then you can style the main-wrapper element instead of the body

```
.main-wrapper {
    background-image: url(../img/planet.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: When you use `background-size:cover` the image can overflow because it must cover the entire container while preserving its ratio.